# Why do I get an "Undefined reference error" when implementing a singleton class?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'am trying to implement a method that returns me an instance of the class, but it's is crashing when it tries to create the instance at the first time. I don't know how to implement the singleton in C++/QT

Main

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "carro.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Carta* nueva;
    nueva->getInstance();
    nueva->setColor("rojo");
    cout << nueva->getColor() << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Carro.h

```
#ifndef CARRO_H
#define CARRO_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Carta{

private:
    string cara; //valor
    string palo; //simbolo
    string color;
    string direccion;

    static Carta* m_instance;

public:
    //constructor
    Carta(){
    }

   static Carta* getInstance(){
       if(!m_instance){
           m_instance = new Carta;
       }
       return m_instance;
    }

    string getDireccion(){
        return direccion;
    }

    void setColor(string pcolor){
        color = pcolor;
    }

    string getColor(){
        return this->color;
    }

    string getPalo(){
        return this->palo;
    }

    string getCara(){
        return this->cara;
    }

    //print
    string print(){
        return (cara + " de " + palo + " Color: "+color);
    }    
};

#endif // CARRO_H
```

Comment: QT is completely unrelated here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've been missing to define `static Carta* m_instance;`, hence the linker error:

```
    Carta* Carta::m_instance = nullptr;
```

---

However I'd rather recommend [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289), if you're really sure you need a singleton:

```
static Carta* getInstance() {
    static Carta m_instance;
    return &m_instance;
}
```

or

```
static Carta& getInstance() {
    static Carta m_instance;
    return m_instance;
}
```

---

Also for accessing the singleton you should have some code like

```
Carta* nueva = Carta::getInstance();
nueva->setColor("rojo");
cout << nueva->getColor() << endl;
```

or with the reference vesion

```
Carta& nueva = Carta::getInstance();
nueva.setColor("rojo");
cout << nueva.getColor() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are incorrect:

```
Carta* nueva;
nueva->getInstance();
```

`nueva` isn't initialized to anything, so deferencing it in the next line results in undefined behavior.

What it looks like you're intending to do is the following:

```
Carta* nueva = Carta::getInstance();
```

Comment: That's true, but why not fix the primary error first??

Answer (score 0):

```
Carta* nueva;
nueva->getInstance();
nueva->setColor("rojo");
```

This is incorrect.These lines of codes exactly say to the computer :

1.`Carta* nueva` Make a pointer to a Carta variable name nueva. Don't forget that at this point, the pointer is NULL.

2.`nueva->getInstance()` This mean access the nueva pointer ( that is still null) and get the method getInstance(). Since getInstance is a static function, it should be use in this way `Carta::getInstance();` You have to use the class instead of a variable and the operator :: to access static members. After you put it in your variable nueva so it would give this :
`nueva = Carta::getInstance();`

So the correct writing would be :

```
Carta* nueva;
nueva = Carta::getInstance();
nueva->setColor("rojo");
```

Comment: That's true, but why not fix the primary error first??

Comment: I dont see which error your talking about?

Comment: Ahh you right he didnt initialize his pointer

Comment: The one that OP implied in their question: "undefined reference to `Carta::m_instance`".

Comment: It's not about _initializing_, but _definition_.

Comment: Your wrong on the error , it look for the method getInstance so it say undefinid method getInstance . The variable is correct.

Comment: _"Your wrong on the error , it look for the method getInstance so it say undefinid method getInstance ."_ Nope, I'm pretty sure that a declaration like `static Carta* m_instance;` needs a definition as `Carta* Carta::m_instance = nullptr;`in a translation unit.
`

Comment: Only op could tell us the error

Comment: `Undefined reference` was mentioned from the beginning, and `getInstance()` isn't a candidate from the code sample. But I agree the question should have been clearer about that.